# azure devops , library , open new tab

Tags: azure-devops

open multiple variable groups

when I click control and then click on variable group , is not open in a new tab, is stay in same tab

and I want to open it in new window

so some 1 have solution for it?

Comment: This is your browser, not Azure DevOps.

Comment: I use google chrome

Comment: The choice of browser doesn't have anything to do with it--it's an (intentional?) decision on Azure DevOps' part.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that Azure Devops doesn’t support to open the Variable Groups in a new Browser tab.

I can fully understand youre requirement.It would be easier to edit if you could open multiple variable groups in a new tab.

Refer to this suggestion ticket: [Pipelines Library - open variable group in new window/tab](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pipelines-library-open-variable-group-in-new-windo/1549922). You can vote and add comment in this ticket.

For a workaround, you can copy the variable group overview site to new tab and then you can open another variable group.

Overview site example:

```
https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_library?itemType=VariableGroups
```